# Assistance with Powershell Do While loop

Tags: powershell

I am writing a powershell script to create a new user in AD and then add a mailbox to them.  The issue I am experiencing is that the script runs too fast and tries to jump to the next step (enabling the user mailbox) before the user has replicated across the domain.

I setup a do While loop to have the script wait to see the user before it moves on to enabling the mailbox but it doesn't seem to be working. What I want to do is have it wait while the value returned is an error and then proceed when it is able to get the user.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Script is below:

```
start-sleep -s 1
do {
    start-sleep -s 1
    $userExists = get-aduser -Identity $username  | select -expandProperty enabled 
    write-host "." -nonewline
} while ($userExists -eq $False)
```

Comment: I was able to resolve this by changing the loop exit to be  
   while ($userExists -ne $True)
 and nulling out the value prior to the loop with 
    $UserExists = $Null.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to solve your dilemma, one of which you may not know exists.  As to your question, the loop isn't breaking because `$false` is a boolean.  Boolean's are a specific data type in Powershell.  What you want to compare to is `$null` as your `$userExists` variable is null unless the cmdlet returns a user object.

The option which I recommend you use is that you specify the Domain Controller to the exchange cmdlet (likely `Enable-Mailbox`) with the `-DomainController` parameter.

You can get what Domain Controller a system is communicating with by using the following code:

```
$DC = (Get-ADDomainController).HostName
```